# is it possible to build fragmented Ipv4 packet, and detect tear drop atack in xdp / ebpf program?

Tags: ebpf, xdp-bpf

Well, i'm trying to realize tear drop atack packet filtering based on the eBPF and xdp driver. And i dont know how to do it... Is it possible to detect ipv4 fragment overlaping by using these instruments?

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you only need to be able to remember the size and offset of IP fragments to detect such attacks. You can do that using [a BPF map](https://prototype-kernel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bpf/ebpf_maps.html).

Comment: but how can i remember N fragments for only one 'full' packet, when ebpf filter millions of different fragmented packets?

Comment: Do you mean how to associate a given fragment to its full packet? Isn't that what the identification field of the IPv4 header is for?